# Bash - Connect to Docker container and execute commands in redis-cli

Tags: bash, docker, redis

I'm trying to create a simple script which would:

1. Connect to docker container's BASH shell
2. Go into redis-cli
3. Perform a `flushall` command in redis-cli

So far, I have this in my `docker_script.sh` (this basically copies the manual procedure):

```
docker exec -it redis /bin/bash
redis-cli
flushall
```

However, when I run it, it only connects to the container's BASH shell and doesn't do anything else. Then, if I type `exit` into the container's BASH shell, it outputs this:

```
root@5ce358657ee4:/data# exit
exit
./docker_script.sh: line 2: redis-cli: command not found
./docker_script.sh: line 3: keys: command not found
```

Why is the `command not found` if commands `redis-cli` and `flushall` exist and are working in the container when I perform the same procedure manually? How do I "automate" it by creating such a small BASH script?

Thank you

Comment: Do you need the `docker exec` step or the intermediate shell at all; can you just run `redis-cli` from the host, connecting to the container's published port?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Seems like you're trying to run `/bin/bash` inside the redis container, while the `redis-cli` and `flushall` commands are scheduled after in your current shell instance. Try passing in your `redis-cli` command to bash like this:

```sh
docker exec -it redis /bin/bash -c "redis-cli FLUSHALL"
```

The `-c` is used to tell bash to read a command from a string.

Excerpt from the `man` page:

```
-c string If the -c option is present, then commands are read from
                 string.   If  there are arguments after the string, they
                 are assigned to the positional parameters, starting with
                 $0.
```

To answer your further question in the comments, you want to run a single script, `redis_flushall.sh` to run that command. The contents of that file are:

```
docker exec -it redis /bin/bash -c redis-cli auth MyRedisPass; flushall
```

Breaking that down, you are calling `redis-cli auth MyRedisPass` as a bash command, and `flushall` as another bash command. The issue is, `flushall` is not a valid command, you'd want to call `redis-cli flushall instead`. Command chaining is something that has to be implemented in a CLI application deliberately, not something that falls out of the cracks.

If you replace the contents of your script with the following, it should work, i.e., after `;` add a `redis-cli` call before specifying the `flushall` command.

```
docker exec -it redis /bin/bash -c redis-cli auth MYSTRONGPASSWORD; redis-cli FLUSHALL
```

Comment: Thank you! This helped. One last question perhaps which came to my mind: how do I pass a command which consists of multiple words? For example, if I want to authenticate in redis by issuing a command like `auth MyStrongPassword`, how do I pass it to the `-c` option properly, to not make it think like it's 2 separate commands (`auth` and `MyStrongPassword`)?

Comment: It won't think it's two separate commands unless you separate them with `&&` or `;`, as far as I know. Since bash accepts multi word commands, as we've seen with `redis-cli FLUSHALL`, it stands to reason the parser wouldn't treat 
`auth MyStrongPassword` as two separate commands.

Comment: Thank you for your reply, but it seems like that could not be the case though.
If I modify my script to look like this: `docker exec -it redis /bin/bash -c "redis-cli auth MyStrongPassword FLUSHALL"`, then if I execute it, it returns this: `(error) WRONGPASS invalid username-password pair or user is disabled.`. However, if I perform the same commands manually, I am able to authenticate myself in redis-cli.

Comment: How did you execute that? Opening a bash interactive session to redis and running that command gives me the same error. Using this command for bash -c seems to work:
```docker exec -it redis /bin/bash -c redis-cli auth MYSTRONGPASSWORD; redis-cli FLUSHALL```

Comment: These are the contents of my `redis_flushall.sh` Bash script: `docker exec -it redis /bin/bash -c redis-cli auth MyRedisPass; flushall`. However, when I run my `redis_flushall.sh` script, it just ends at the redis-cli command without being authenticated and without flushing the Redis DB.

Comment: I'll update my answer, that's something a bit different

Comment: Which part of my answer didn't solve your problem, prompting you to unaccept it, @neisor ?

Comment: you mentioned that you'll update your answer, so I wanted to re-accept it again after the update. Nonetheless, your answer works if there is no need to authenticate in redis-cli, however, it does not if the authentication is required. Thank you

Comment: I did update my answer, see the bottom of it, and it should work with authentication

Comment: Indeed, it does work now. Thank you very much for your efforts! Much appreciated!

Answer (score 2):

The above proposed solution with auth still got me an error

`(error) NOAUTH Authentication required`

This worked for me:

```
docker exec -it redis /bin/sh -c 'redis-cli -a MYPASSWORD FLUSHALL'
```